# IOS: warning in a loop with NSString and an object

Tags: ios, object, for-loop, nsstring

I have this loop to check the correspondence between two word but I have an alert that say

```
"Collection expression type 'NSString *' may not respond to 'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count'."
```

the code is:

```
for (id object in array ) 
    {
        for (word in [object name]) {
            @autoreleasepool {
                NSRange r = [word rangeOfString:searchText];
                if(r.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    if(r.location== 0)
                    {
                        [search_array addObject:object];
                        break; 
                    }
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

the warning is for "[object name]", why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very clear by the message `NSString * may not respond...`

For `for(.. in ..)` you need a collection. and `NSString` is not a collection.

As you have

```
for (word in [object name])
```

---

Also I see you have nested loop. First one is giving you one object at a time.

I guess you need to do something like this: **Not compiler checked + your logic may be different*

```
for (id object in array ) 
    {
        NSString *word = [object name];
            @autoreleasepool {
                NSRange r = [word rangeOfString:searchText];
                if(r.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    if(r.location== 0)
                    {
                        [search_array addObject:object];
                        break; 
                    }
                }
                counter++;
            }
    }
```

Comment: and what's the solution?

Comment: aaaaaaahhhh thansk!!!!